# s3 Download button in nextjs

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

Im implementing a download button on s3 bucket inside a nextjs app. I want to be able to download video files stored at my "object key". However I havent been able to get it to work, I've tried several approaches none have worked. I double checked IAM config as well as my bucket policy and CORS and everything is fine. I think i need another pair of eyes on this. Thanks in advance.

This is my code that handles the request :

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand, } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';

type Data = {
  url?: string;
  error?: string;
};

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method Not Allowed' });
    return;
  }

  const { objectKey } = req.query;

  if (typeof objectKey !== 'string' || !objectKey) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Object key is required and must be a string' });
    return;
  }
 
  const s3ClientConfig = {
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID || '',
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY || '',
    },
  };

  if (!s3ClientConfig.credentials.accessKeyId || !s3ClientConfig.credentials.secretAccessKey) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'AWS credentials are missing' });
    return;
  }

  
const s3Client = new S3Client(s3ClientConfig);

  try {
    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: objectKey,
    });

    const url = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
    res.status(200).json({ url });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error generating presigned URL:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to generate presigned URL' });
  }
}
```

download button:

```
 'use client'
import React from 'react';

// If you have a specific type for the props, declare it like this:
interface DownloadButtonProps {
  objectKey: string;
}

const DownloadButton: React.FC<DownloadButtonProps> = ({ objectKey }) => {
  const handleDownload = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/generateUrl?objectKey=${encodeURIComponent(objectKey)}`);
        if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Failed to get download URL');

        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.url) {
            window.location.href = data.url; // Navigate to the URL, triggering the file download
        } else {
            throw new Error('No URL returned');
        }
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error('Download error:', error);
        alert('Failed to download file: ' + error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleDownload} className="download-button">
      Download File
    </button>
  );
};

export default DownloadButton;
```

Comment: you should be able to easily narrow this down. What is the server actually returning?